# Can I add a static cover image to a file viewer web part hosting audio files?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-site, fileviewer

I've got a number of file viewer web parts that are used to host audio clips for users to listen to on a SharePoint site.

However, I can't see any way to add in a static cover image when i apply an audio file.  Am I missing something or does anyone have any good ideas?  Is there a way to do this on SharePoint without having to look into how to apply an image to the file itself (if that's even possible)?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that we cannot add the static cover image into the file viewer web part, because the file viewer web part only can view files.

You could consider adding video in the file viewer web part and setting the static cover image in the video.